# Printing to LPT1 in C#

Tags: c#, file, driver, printing

How do you print directly to a dot matrix printer in C# using file LPT1.

I did it on C++ with fopen, but I don't know how to do it in c#.

thank you very much

Comment: I've got an answer, but my name's not Michael

Comment: My guess is he copied it from an email he sent to someone asking the same question, just forgot to take his name out.

Comment: Geeze... dot-matrix printers are still in use?  I remember programming to one circa 1992, but I haven't even seen one in years.

Comment: To those wondering about the whole Michael bit - the original question (see revisions) was addressed to an unknown Michael...

Comment: Dot matrix printers are often used in industrial and some retail establishments - cheap, rugged, can handle multipart forms, can feed off a box below with thousands of custom forms.  You can buy them new for this purpose even today.

Comment: Dot Matrix is still extremely prevalent in industry. Still the most common way to print multipart forms.

Comment: They're annoyingly loud though.

Comment: You should listen to a line printer for an idea of what a loud printer really is.

Comment: most of the time they are on a production floor or a shipping dock, so loud is a relative term. :)

Comment: I think our finance dept still has one in a (large, ineffective) soundproof cabinet.

Comment: You guys are ... conversing on SO in the comments of a question?  Shame on you!  - Michael

Answer (score 15):

Set up the printer in Windows as Generic/Text Only, then print to it.

Here's the code I use to print to a label printer that has its own encoded text format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace whatever {

public class RawPrinterHelper
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
        Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
        IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
        DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
        bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

        di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
        di.pDataType = "RAW";

        // Open the printer.
        if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
        {
            // Start a document.
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                // Start a page.
                if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                {
                    // Write your bytes.
                    bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                    EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
        // about why not.
        if (bSuccess == false)
        {
            dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        }
        return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
    {
        // Open the file.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
        // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
        bool bSuccess = false;
        // Your unmanaged pointer.
        IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
        int nLength;

        nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
        // Read the contents of the file into the array.
        bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
        // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
        pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
        // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
        bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
        // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
        return bSuccess;
    }
    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
        IntPtr pBytes;
        Int32 dwCount;
        // How many characters are in the string?
        dwCount = szString.Length;
        // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
        // the string to ANSI text.
        pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
        // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
        bool success = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
        return success;
    }
}
}
```

Then this is called from another class like this:

```
    private bool PrintLabels(string printerName)
    {
        return RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(printerName, this.Text);
    }
```

(edit: if anyone sees any major fubars related to unmanaged resources, let me know in the comments)

Comment: lol, actually, a new meme.  I'm starting all my questions from now on with "Hi Michael" :)

Comment: LOL, this could become a famous Stack Overflow blooper.

Comment: Uggh...now someone is going to start using a Michael tag.

Comment: If I had editing rights, I would so tag this Michael right now, :).

Comment: I hope I don't have my editting rights revoked.  Tagged as "Michael"

Comment: What we need is a Michael badge: Answer a question directed to a specific person, where you were not the intended person, but share their name.

Comment: Thank you!  I needed this answer today.  + 1 to you.

Comment: 3 years later, i'm picking up this blooper Michael :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you cannot print to the device "LPT1" but to a "dumb teletype printer" that you have to install first. If they exist in modern windows....
So you should print to "mydumbprinter" which in its turn uses LPT1 as printer port.
It appeared to me as I followed the Source link by Cocowalla above - there you select a printer in a PrinterDialog. The resulting printer name would more likely be "Laserjet" than "LPT1".

Answer (score 0):

In C# its possible, first you need to connect to that port using the `CreateFile` method then open a filestream to that port to finally write to it.
Here is a sample class that writes two lines to the printer on `LPT1`.

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourNamespace
{
public static class Print2LPT
        {
            [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
            static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, FileAccess dwDesiredAccess,uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, FileMode dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

            public static bool Print()
            {
                string nl = Convert.ToChar(13).ToString() + Convert.ToChar(10).ToString();
                bool IsConnected= false;

                string sampleText ="Hello World!" + nl +
                "Enjoy Printing...";     
                try
                {
                    Byte[] buffer = new byte[sampleText.Length];
                    buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sampleText);

                    SafeFileHandle fh = CreateFile("LPT1:", FileAccess.Write, 0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
                    if (!fh.IsInvalid)
                    {
                        IsConnected= true;                    
                        FileStream lpt1 = new FileStream(fh,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                        lpt1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        lpt1.Close();
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string message = ex.Message;
                }

                return IsConnected;
            }
        }
}
```

Assuming your printer is connected on the `LPT1` port, if not you will need to adjust the `CreateFile` method to match the port you are using.

you can call the method anywhere in your program with the following line

```
Print2LPT.Print();
```

I think this is the shortest and most efficient solution to your problem.