# C# POS fast receipt printing

Tags: c#, receipt

I'd like to print the receipt of my POS application (Winform C#)
My first attempt is using crystal report, but it's no fast enough when there're many customers in line, even some of them will leave the line.
So I have idea to print in DOS mode. I create a dummy file and send it to PRN.
It's working well, fast enough but then I have a thought.. Is there any other better way to do? I mean it's not by creating a dummy file first, but print line by line from C# itself?
of course it must be fast.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: here pos applications use other reporting engines to print. The problem is that there fiscal devices that read these print jobs. And that would make receipt even slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my answer here: [print on dot matrix printer in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449777/print-on-dot-matrix-printer-in-net)

No need to create an intermediary file and send it to PRN; just add a **Generic / Text Only** printer, and then print to that driver. To do that, open a file handle to "PRN" or "LPT1" in C#, then you can directly print to it based on the file handle you obtained from opening "PRN" or "LPT1"

---

**UPDATE**

Code here might help you: [Printing to LPT1 in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543155)